# Export an Excel chart and include a textbox

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba, export

I have this code that exports an Excel chart and it's working fine.

```
Sub ExportChart(ByVal fileName As String)
     '   Export a selected chart as a picture    
    Const sPicType$ = ".png"
    Dim sChartName$
    Dim objChart As ChartObject 
    Set objChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)
    If objChart Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    sPath = fileName & sPicType
    objChart.Chart.Export fileName:=sPath, FilterName:="PNG"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True     
End Sub
```

Except that I added a textarea on the chart and it doesn't show in the exported image.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Just to ask the obvious question: If you copy objChart to another sheet within the same workbook: Is the textbox copied too?

Comment: No, because the textbox is not part of the chart.

Comment: If the chart is selected when you create the text box, it will be a part of the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select the chart before you insert the text box, it will be a part of the chart and export properly.

Comment: If you didn't select the chart before inserting the textbox, you can copy the textbox, select the chart, and paste. The textbox is now part of the chart, and you can position it as desired.